# Flash drive problems

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I bought a what was supposed to be a 64 gb flash drive and I checked it out and I found out it was a 90 something gigabyte removable drive and it also has some weird files that can't be deleted,fragmented,optimized I am really concerned that it is not a good thing

Comment: Does this flash drive have a brand? Some flash drives come with some extra stuff.   Why/how did you decide it was a different size than it was supposed to be?

Comment: Pny it has some Arabian writing on it and files like an 8@ file

Comment: Also had said on the box it was 64 gb an said 67.23 gb used 20.5available

Comment: It looks like one of those counterfeit flash drives. To determine the true capacity, use [H2testw](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml).